# How access items in an array based on button combinations in ios

Tags: ios, uitouch

Before I start I want to explain that I'm looking for a general solution to my inquiry, I don't have any code to show because I haven't the faintest idea of how to start. Let's say I have a program in which I have 4 buttons, two on the right (red and blue), two on the left (white and yellow). If I were to press a certain combination of buttons I want to get a specific output an example would be if I touch the red button and then the white one the word "cow" appears or if were to touch the white one then the red one the word "chicken" appears. Is there any documentation that anyone knows of that can help me with my problem? Can this even be done with an array?

Comment: If you have 4 buttons, and they can be pressed simultaneously in any combination, that's 15 combinations (assuming no buttons pressed is not a "combination").  So consider it to be a 4-bit binary number with possible values 1-15.  You can use a 16-entry array with the first array element empty.

Comment: But your question implies that you want to press two buttons in some order -- 1 then 2, 3 then 4, 4 then 2, etc.  Thus there are 3 possible next-button choices for each of the 4 initial buttons, and a total of 12 possible 2-button combinations.  Easy enough to enumerate and put into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HotLicks has a valid answer, but I think an NSDictionary is a better solution. Create keys based on button presses, like:

```
@{ @"RedWhite" : @"Cow",
      @"WhiteRed" : @"Chicken" };
```

Your code will be easier to read, and you can support three presses easily (assuming you're working with a timer that you invalidate after each press) by just adding another key; no recalculating your array:

```
 @{ @"RedWhiteBlue" : @"America" };
```

Comment: I do have one question, how do I set key combinations for NSDictionary values?

Comment: What do you mean by key combinations? Multiple keys? You can only set key, value pairs for dictionary items, so you'll have to create a hash of the button presses like I've shown above.